# Law of Total Probabilities for continuous pdf $ f_{y} (y) = \int_{R}^{} f_{y|x}(s|t)f_{x}(t)dt $?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Does the law of total probabilites hold also in the case of continuous pdf?

$ f_{y} (y) =  \int_{R}^{} f_{y|x}(s|t)f_{x}(t)dt $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What is s? A typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close; $~~y$ needs to be the free variable on both sides of the equality.

$$f_Y(y) = \int_\Bbb R f_{X}(t)\,f_{Y\mid X}(y\mid t)\,\mathrm d t$$